# HorizontalScrollView pushes my widgets to the left side

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I am trying to make my `layout` to be horizontally scrollable, but when I do that, it pushes all my `widgets` to the left side.

This is my original `XML` where the layout is exactly what I want:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBack"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Main Screen" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnBack"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Coordinate Calculator"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/num2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/num1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/num1"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:ems="5"
            android:hint="       y"
            android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="4" />

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/num3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/num2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/num2"
            android:ems="5"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:hint="       r"
            android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="4" />

        <EditText android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:id="@+id/num1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:ems="5"
            android:hint="       x"
            android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCalculate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/num2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/num1"
             android:text="Calculate" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/btnClear"
             style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnCalculate"
             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnCalculate"
             android:layout_below="@+id/btnCalculate"
             android:text="Clear All" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/display"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_below="@+id/btnClear"
             android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is the `layout` for the `XML` above:

[image]

This is the `XML` for the horizontally scrollable layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <!-- all the same widgets -->

        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Now here is the layout for this `XML`:

[image]

This is usually how I modify my `XML` to make it horizontally scrollable, but this time it's not working.

How can I make this horizontally scrollable without changing the layout at all?

Answer (score -1):

use property **android:fadingEdge="none"** in scrollView